# Big Query - Same scheduled query but different time to complete

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using on-demand pricing. I have created a scheduled query. This runs every 1 hour. It normally takes around 4-5 minutes. Data is constantly increasing as its order data. But today 1scheduled query took around 51 minutes to complete. Below is statistics of that job

```
    "creationTime": "1655471342447",
    "startTime": "1655471342493",
    "endTime": "1655474394141",
    "totalBytesProcessed": "66814437651",
    "query": {
      "totalBytesProcessed": "66814437651",
      "totalBytesBilled": "66815262720",
      "totalSlotMs": "2203637966",
      "statementType": "SCRIPT"
    },
    "totalSlotMs": "2203637966",
    "numChildJobs": "2"
  }
```

In the next run it again run in around 5 min, below is statistics of that job

```
"statistics": {
    "creationTime": "1655474941671",
    "startTime": "1655474941712",
    "endTime": "1655475151818",
    "totalBytesProcessed": "66818481321",
    "query": {
      "totalBytesProcessed": "66818481321",
      "totalBytesBilled": "66819457024",
      "totalSlotMs": "182181893",
      "statementType": "SCRIPT"
    },
    "totalSlotMs": "182181893",
    "numChildJobs": "2"
  }
```

If you check the totalBytesProcessed, in both the query it around same, but totalSlotMs and time taken to complete the job has high difference.
What could be the reason for log query execution ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the BigQuery documentation:

```
You can combine both models to fit your needs. With on-demand pricing, you pay for what you use. However, your queries run using a shared pool of slots, so performance can vary. With flat-rate pricing, you purchase guaranteed capacity, with a discounted price for a longer-term commitment. For more information about which pricing to choose for your workloads, see Workload management using Reservations.
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#overview_of_pricing

Comment: So is it because there might be other queries that were running at the same time ?